# Error: Failed to resolve: retrofit-2.9.0-2.9.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am running the following code:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
```

upon doing sync I get an error:

> Failed to resolve: retrofit-2.9.0-2.9.0

Answer (score 3):

These are the **latest** `retrofit` dependencies.

```
  implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try the below lines

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

sometimes gradle gives such errors.. you can create dependencies through module settings. check it.. it works.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Just try to make a File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... and retrofit dependencies will be resolved.